# Command to change binary mlf terms into Subscripted mlf terms?

Tags: conversion, binary

I express multilinear functions in the following format. Is there any ready command to convert them to multilinear functions easily?

**Input**

```
posTerms = {2, 4, 9, 13, 19};
negTerms = {6, 11, 26};
IntegerString[posTerms, 2]
IntegerString[negTerms, 2]

{"10", "100", "1001", "1101", "10011"}
{"110", "1011", "11010"}
```

**Intended Output**

```
x_2+x_3+x_4*x_1+x_4*x_3*x_1+x_5*x_2*x_1-(x_3*x_2+x_4*x_2*x_1+x_5*x_4*x_2)
```

**Intended Output in Mathematica**

```
Subscript[p, 2]+Subscript[p, 3]+Subscript[p, 4]*Subscript[p, 1]+Subscript[p, 4]*Subscript[p, 3]*Subscript[p, 1]+Subscript[p, 5]*Subscript[p, 2]*Subscript[p, 1]

-Subscript[p, 3]*Subscript[p, 2]-Subscript[p, 4]*Subscript[p, 2]*Subscript[p, 1]-Subscript[p, 5]*Subscript[p, 4]*Subscript[p, 2]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about

```
FromCoefficientRules[#, Subscript[x, #] & /@ Reverse@Range@Length@#[[1, 1]]] &@
    Thread[PadLeft@IntegerDigits[posTerms, 2] -> 1] - 
   FromCoefficientRules[#, Subscript[x, #] & /@ Reverse@Range@Length@#[[1, 1]]] &@
 Thread[PadLeft@IntegerDigits[negTerms, 2] -> 1]
```

[image]

As belisarius wrote in comment it can be reduced to

```
Subtract @@ (FromCoefficientRules[#, Subscript[x, #] & /@ Reverse@Range@Length@#[[1, 1]]] &@
     Thread[PadLeft@IntegerDigits[#, 2] -> 1] & /@ {posTerms, negTerms})
```

Also there is another short solution

```
Subtract @@ (Total[Times @@ MapIndexed[Subscript[x, #2[[1]]]^# &, Reverse[#]] & /@ 
   IntegerDigits[#, 2]] & /@ {posTerms, negTerms})
```

It is shorter than belisarius's solution by 13 characters :)

Comment: @hhh It is because I incorrectly aligned `posTerms` with `negTerms`. See my update, does it work now?

Comment: I cannot fully understand this: suppose I specify the terms with `{1,3,7}` to mean `p_1p_3p_7` -- is it easier to get the multilinear term from it? So here terms `Subscript[x, #] & /@ {1, 3, 7}` and now just multiplication. Where is the multiplication?

Comment: Moved the new q [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/36760/how-to-get-monomials-multiplied-by-each-other).

Answer (score 2):

Also

```
-Differences[Tr[Times @@@ (Position[Reverse@#, 1] & /@ # /. {n_Integer} -> 
                            Subscript[x, n])] & /@ (IntegerDigits[#, 2] & /@ {posTerms, negTerms})]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Equivalent:

```
Subtract@@Tr/@ Map[Times @@ (Position[Reverse@#, 1] /. {n_Integer} -> 
                           Subscript[x, n]) &, (IntegerDigits[#, 2] & /@ {posTerms, negTerms}), {2}]
```

Comment: I like shorter +1.

Comment: @hhh So here you have a shorter version of ybeltukov's answer too `Subtract @@ (FromCoefficientRules[#, 
       Subscript[x, #] & /@ Reverse@Range@Length@#[[1, 1]]] &@
     Thread[PadLeft@IntegerDigits[#, 2] -> 1] & /@ {posTerms, 
    negTerms})`