# How to get monomials multiplied by each other?

Tags: conversion

Suppose `Subscript[x, #] & /@ {1, 3, 7}` that returns `{x_1,x_3,x_7}`. Now how can I get `x_1x_3x_7`?

**Tried it already**...

> [image]

*P.s. I am trying to understand [this thread](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/35539/command-to-change-binary-mlf-terms-into-subscripted-mlf-terms) deeper about converting binary mlfs to mlfs.*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is due to precedence. Need to use `()` in this case.

```
Times @@ (Subscript[x, #] & /@ {1, 3, 7})
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

See this [when-is-fg-not-the-same-as-fg](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/30425/) topic for table of precedence in Mathematica.

Comment: Yes but my Mathematica is returning `{x,3x,7x}` -- oouch brackets missing?! So my version operated on the Subscript thing, not the whole thing. Thank you! +1

Answer (score 3):

Two more solutions:

```
Times @@ Thread@Subscript[x, {1, 3, 7}]
```

In the notebook it can be written more compactly

[image]

The second one shows the behavior of `/@`

```
Subscript[x, #] & /@ Unevaluated@Times[1, 3, 7]
```

[image]