# Conversion of binary matrix of mlf into multilinear function, any ready function for this?

Tags: conversion, binary

I convert [here](http://pastie.org/8470310) only one term $x_1x_3x_7$ from the binary matrix by first getting the reversed binary 1010001 and then miggling with the data. I know I could convert the columns into binaries and then use solutions [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/35539/command-to-change-binary-mlf-terms-into-subscripted-mlf-terms) but I feel there must be something builtin: I am trying to convert binary form of multilinear function simply to its symbolic form where the MLF is expressed as a matrix below..

> **Is there anything built in to convert the binary matrix into the corresponding multilinear function?**

**Input**

> [image]

**Intended output**

> $x_1x_3x_7+x_1x_3x_5x_6+x_1x_4x_7+x_1x_4x_5x_6-x_2x_3x_7-x_2x_3x_5x_6-x_2x_4x_7-x_2x_4x_5x_6$

Answer (score 2):

I think you need something like this

```
Total[#1 - #2] & @@ Partition[#, Length[#]/2] &[
 Times @@ MapIndexed[Subscript[x, #2[[1]]]^# &, Boole[MCSs], {2}]]
```

[image]

Comment: @hhh `Transpose` isn't necessary here. Without it the solution becomes more compact. See my update: I delete `Transpose` and use `@@` instead of `@@@`. It works because `Times` has a `Listable` attribute.

Comment: @hhh I think you need time to solve your problem. Not a hour, but a day or a week. After update this problem seems too narrow to the community (read: I don't understand it completely).

Comment: @hhh - it is ok to have your contact information in your user profile, but please do not leave identifying information in comments. Also, if the issue can be solved that easily, it can be solved in chat. By definition, if a problem is solved by email, it is not then publicly available to help the community. Part of the rationale of this site is also to help future visitors with questions similar to those already posted, which email solutions do not do.

Answer (score 1):

```
MCSs = {{1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0}, {1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1}, 
        {1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0}, 
        {0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0}};
var = Subscript[x, #] & /@ Range[7];

(Plus @@ Inner[#2^#1 &, MCSs[[;; 4]], var, Times]) - 
(Plus @@ Inner[#2^#1 &, MCSs[[5 ;;]], var, Times])
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Alternatively, one could use:

```
Plus @@ Times @@@ (Pick[var, #, 1] & /@ MCSs[[;; 4]]) -
Plus @@ Times @@@ (Pick[var, #, 1] & /@ MCSs[[5 ;;]])
```

Comment: You are correct! `Inner[Power, 
 Subscript[x, #] & /@ Range[7], {1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1}, Times]` returns `x_1x_3x_7`, amazing! Now looping required, anyway excellent idea! So easy to read to consider zero/ones as powers ^-^ +1

Comment: @hhh Power wouldn't be correct. You need its variables in reverse.

Answer (score 1):

`FromCoefficientRules` is an approach. Apologies for any transcription errrors. The MCSs matrix was an image not copyable code.

```
MCS = {{1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0}, {1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
    0, 1}, {1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 1, 0, 
    1, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0}};
```

This matrix rows can be interpreted as ordered list of the exponents of multinomial term.
Generate the variable list:

```
var = Subscript[x, #] & /@ Range[7];
```

Generate the rules for term->coefficient:

```
pos = Thread[MCS[[Range[4]]] -> 1];
neg = Thread[MCS[[Range[4] + 4]] -> -1];
```

Use`FromCoefficientRules` to assemble the multinomial:

```
FromCoefficientRules[Join[pos, neg], var]
```

yields:

```
Subscript[x, 1] Subscript[x, 3] Subscript[x, 5] Subscript[x, 6] - 
 Subscript[x, 2] Subscript[x, 3] Subscript[x, 5] Subscript[x, 6] + 
 Subscript[x, 1] Subscript[x, 4] Subscript[x, 5] Subscript[x, 6] - 
 Subscript[x, 2] Subscript[x, 4] Subscript[x, 5] Subscript[x, 6] + 
 Subscript[x, 1] Subscript[x, 3] Subscript[x, 7] - 
 Subscript[x, 2] Subscript[x, 3] Subscript[x, 7] + 
 Subscript[x, 1] Subscript[x, 4] Subscript[x, 7] - 
 Subscript[x, 2] Subscript[x, 4] Subscript[x, 7]
```